# std::function vs auto call to different overload

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, overloading, auto

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void f(const std::function<void()>&)  
{  
    std::cout << "In f(const std::function<void()>&)." << std::endl;  
}  

void f(std::function<void()>&&)
{  
    std::cout << "In f(std::function<void()>&&)." << std::endl;  
}  

int main()  
{  
    auto func = []() { std ::cout << "func\n"; };
    f(func); // calls void f(std::function<void()>&&)

    /*const*/ std::function<void()> func2 = []() { std ::cout << "func\n"; };
    f(func2); // calls void f(const std::function<void()>&)

    f([]() { std ::cout << "func\n"; }); // calls void f(std::function<void()>&&)

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know why the first call to `f` (when I use `auto` and the lambda function) calls the `void f(std::function<void()>&&)` overload and not the `void f(const std::function<void()>&)`, which is instead called by the second call to `f` when I declare the variable as a (`const`) `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: The type of a lambda is not `std::function<w/e>`, so the first call triggers an implicit conversion. Is that the source of your misunderstanding?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yes, how is the implicit conversion is defined and why does it prefer the rvalue reference overload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the 1st case, i.e. with the usage of `auto`, the type of `func` is a unique lambda closure type, which is not of `std::function<void()>`, but could implicitly convert to [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

> Instances of std::function can store, copy, and invoke any Callable target -- functions, lambda expressions, bind expressions, or other function objects, as well as pointers to member functions and pointers to data members.

After the conversion we'll get an rvalue of type `std::function<void()>`, and binding rvalue-reference to rvalue is better match than binding lvalue-reference to rvalue in [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences), then the 2nd overload is invoked.

> 3) A standard conversion sequence S1 is better than a standard conversion sequence S2 if
>
> c) or, if not that, both S1 and S2 are binding to a reference parameter to something other than the implicit object parameter of a ref-qualified member function, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue while S2 binds an lvalue reference to an rvalue

For the 2nd case, `func2` is declared as the exact type of `std::function<void()>`, then for `f(func2);` no conversion is required. As a named variable `func2` is an lvalue, which can't be bound to rvalue-reference, then the 1st overload is invoked.

> if an rvalue argument corresponds to non-const lvalue reference parameter or an lvalue argument corresponds to rvalue reference parameter, the function is not viable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that using `auto` has several advantages when declaring a lambda, in terms of performance, compared to `std::function`. I am wondering now what's the penalty of the implicit conversion if you need to pass the lambda to a method that accepts an `std::function`, and if it is better in this scenario to declare the variable as a `std::function` in the first place.

Comment: @Nick In most cases you don't need `std::function`; a function template like `template <typename FUNC> void f(FUNC&& func)` will do the work for you.

Comment: @songyuanyao That requires you to expose your implementation in the header file, which is a non-trivial cost.

Comment: @Nick Whether to store it in a std::function object depends on both (a) will you be calling something that takes a std::function by reference more than once and (b) how big the lambda object is (ie, will std::function have to do a heap allocation to store it?).  Your examples have non-capturing lambdas, which are small enough not to matter.